# utf-8 text is being garbled

Tags: javascript, text, unicode, utf-8

I'm still new to webdev and dealing with character set encodings. I've read http://kunststube.net/encoding/ along with a few other pieces on the subject.

My problem is that I've got a bunch of text that I'm pulling from a server. It is encoded and served as utf-8.

However, when I display the strings, the french / spanish accents are garbled up. I've googled around and it seems JavaScript engines use UCS-2 or UTF-16 internally. Is there something I have to do to get it to treat my text as UTF-8? I have the <meta charset="utf-8"> in my html, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any links, I can't inspect what you are doing directly, but you shouldn't need to do anything special inside JavaScript to get it to work, just make sure all your sources are set to UTF-8 correctly, and that the browser is interpreting them as such.

You may need to make sure your server (Apache? IIS?) is setting the appropriate encode header. For example in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Or in .htaccess there are many ways to do it. A couple of ways:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
```

or specific files:

```
<Files "example.js">
AddCharset UTF-8 .js
</Files>
```

refs:

- https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php
- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset.en

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have meta tag in your html then put it in the header :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

else , you have to declare character encoding in your script file